# ProgressDialog DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-intent, progressdialog, download-manager

in my application I would love to implement a progressDialog to the image download process and after this, i want call the intent ACTION_ATTACH_DATA. currently my code works fine but as you can see when it starts downloading, immediately called the intent. my goal is to show the intent after the download and  with a progressdialog. Thanks for your help :)

code:

```
 Button impostacome = (Button)popupView2.findViewById(R.id.impostacome);
          impostacome.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v) {

         File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Wallpaper");
         boolean success = false;
         if (!folder.exists()) {
             success = folder.mkdirs();
         }
         if (!success) {
         } else {
         }          
    File direct = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");

     if (!direct.exists()) {
         direct.mkdirs();
     }

     DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

     Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse("http://www.brothersapp.com/immaginiapp/wallpaper/1");
     DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
             downloadUri);

     request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
     DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
     | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
     .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("brothersapp download")
     .setDescription("The image is Downloading...")
     .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/brothersapp/", "/1.jpg/");
     mgr.enqueue(request);





     Intent myintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
     Uri sendUri =  Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/brothersapp/1.jpg");    
     myintent.setDataAndType(sendUri, "image/*");
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myintent, "Set As"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DownloadManager works asynchronously. Your code will not wait for download to be completed. If you want to do something when file is downloaded, you need to listen to `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` broadcast.

PS: you do not *show* Intent.

Comment: thanks how do I make the download manager to work with the progress bar? 
maybe I could make the show progressdialog when the download starts and remove it when the download is complete?

Comment: why you want to do that? DownloadManager got own progress bars so I personally see no point duplicating that feature